# Groovy domain index is not bound while splitting an array

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I have created very simple function that should return the first array after splitting it with a char.

```
int add(String version){
    splitVersion = version.split('.')
    echo splitVersion[0]
}
```

I'm calling the function like that: `add("1.0.0")`

And right after that I"m receving this error:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`

It's seem to be that it's not acting like a String at all, and when I try to print `version` it's print the value that sent(1.0.0)

What could be the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The split method receives a regex, so you should use it like this.

```
int add(String version){
   splitVersion = version.split("\\.")
   echo splitVersion[0]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any clue why for `add("1.0.0")` the line `echo splitVersion[2]+1`return `01` instand of `1`?

Comment: while trying to `parseInt` i'm getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.EchoStep.message expects class java.lang.String but received class java.lang.Integer`

Comment: i dont know what echo does, try using `return splitVersion[0]`  instead.

Comment: i'm trying to increment the last index by 1. and instand of getting 1, im getting 01 like concatination..

Comment: yes that is because `splitVersion[0]` is a String, so "0"+1="01"

Comment: while trying to parse it to int, i'm receivng the error above

Comment: i recommend to pay more attention to the errors, but seems to me that echo expects a string, so you would need to do the maths and convert to string again